# Table scroll to defined column

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, html-table

I've a big calendar table to provide a overview of a planning.
I want to always scroll automatically on windowload to "this day", which col has the class .today.
I've already tried to work with JQuery scrollTo, scrollLeft and animate, but nothing works.

The table always start automatically 3 months before. (Now in July, it starts with April)
Here's a quick view of the table.

The "today col" is for example specified like this:

```
<col id='2018y7-31' class='today'> </col>
```

Does anyone know a solution to scroll onload to the/a specific day?

[image: Calendar Table]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $(".today").offset().top
}, 600);
```

Comment: This doesn't scroll to the left side if the col in the table, just scrolls to the top of the entire table (first row).
Even if I change it to `scrollLeft: $(".today.").offset().left` it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work as it is not tested yet

```
 $(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        var x = $(".today").position(); //gets the position of the div element...
         window.scrollTo(x.left, x.top); //window.scrollTo() scrolls the page upto certain position....
                //it takes 2 parameters : (x axis cordinate, y axis cordinate);
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example :

```js
for (let i = 0; i<150; i++){
    $('#header').append('<th>' + i + '</th>');
    $('#body').append('<td>' + i + '</td>');
}

$('td:nth-child(100)').addClass('today');

$(document).ready(function(){
  let offset = $('.today').position().left;
  console.log(offset);
  window.scrollTo(offset, 0);
})
```

```css
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
  <thead>
    <tr id="header">  
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
    <tr id="body"></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helped.